# Generate JWT Token In Java for hasura authorization

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, jwt

We are using spring boot as backend to for only auth and generating jwt token rest is handled in hasura.

I am facing problem in generating JWT properly.

```
public String generateToken(String email,String role,Long id)  {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String,Object> claim =new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("x-hasura-user-id",id);
        claims.put("x-hasura-default-role",role);
        claims.put("x-hasura-allowed-roles", new String[]{"job_seeker", "employer", "admin"});

        claim.put("https://hasura.io/jwt/claims",claims);
        System.out.println(claim);
        return doGenerateToken(claim, email);
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claim, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claim).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + Long.parseLong(tokenValidity))).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret).compact();
    }
```

This is generating jwt token as

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyb3NhbjEyM0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJodHRwczovL2hhc3VyYS5pby9qd3QvY2xhaW1zIjp7IngtaGFzdXJhLWRlZmF1bHQtcm9sZSI6ImFkbWluIiwieC1oYXN1cmEtdXNlci1pZCI6NCwieC1oYXN1cmEtYWxsb3dlZC1yb2xlcyI6WyJqb2Jfc2Vla2VyIiwiZW1wbG95ZXIiLCJhZG1pbiJdfSwiZXhwIjoxNjA5ODU1OTA2LCJpYXQiOjE2MDk4NTExMDZ9.WqJE1xLIsycW92tzFXdq0UHub3qUfQbUvUax9rvks4Q
```

but it hasura is returning Invalid signature. Where as in node

```
 generateToken: (user: any) => {
    const payload = {
      sub: user.email,
      "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
        "x-hasura-default-role": `${user.role.name}`,
        "x-hasura-user-id": `${user.id}`,
        "x-hasura-allowed-roles": ["job_seeker", "employer", "admin"],
      },
    };
    return jwt.sign(payload, secretkey);
  },
```

jwt from node

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJib2hhcmFuaXNjaGFsQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImh0dHBzOi8vaGFzdXJhLmlvL2p3dC9jbGFpbXMiOnsieC1oYXN1cmEtZGVmYXVsdC1yb2xlIjoiam9iX3NlZWtlciIsIngtaGFzdXJhLXVzZXItaWQiOiIyNCIsIngtaGFzdXJhLWFsbG93ZWQtcm9sZXMiOlsiam9iX3NlZWtlciIsImVtcGxveWVyIiwiYWRtaW4iXX0sImlhdCI6MTYwOTg1NDEzMX0.8UDrqvRujakGsEtGEAu1XWl5RsFda8HaA_-97vwY62I
```

using same secret key and algorithm is working perfectly fine. For node i have used jsonwebtoken library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. String should be converted to byte[]:

```
 private String doGenerateToken(Map<String,Object> header,Map<String, Object> claim, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setHeader(header).setClaims(claim).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + Long.parseLong(tokenValidity))).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).compact();
    }
```